# work out how many seconds have expired in total during game play

Tags: algorithm, math, formulas, algebra

~Why the hell has this had down votes.... you people are weird!

Ok so this is a very simply HTML5 and jQuery and PHP game. Sorry to the people who have answered, I forgot to say this is a php script, i have updated here to reflect.

the first level takes 1 minute. Every level after that takes an extra 10 seconds than the last level. like so;

```
level 1 = 60 seconds
level 2 = 70 seconds
level 3 = 80 seconds
level 4 = 90 seconds
```

and so on infinitely.

I need an equation that can figure out what is the total amount of seconds played based on the users level.

level = n
i started with `(n * 10) + (n * 60)` but soon realized that that doesn't account for the last level already being 10 seconds longer than the last. I have temporarily fixed it using a function calling a foreach loop stopping at the level number and returning the value. but i really want an actual equation.

SO i know you wont let me down :-)
Thanks in advance.

this is what i am using;

```
function getnumberofsecondsfromlevel($level){


 $lastlevelseconds = 60;

 while($counter < $level){

     $totalseconds = $lastlevelseconds+$totalseconds;

     $lastlevelseconds = $lastlevelseconds + 10;

 $counter++; 
 } 

return $totalseconds; 

}

$level = $_SESSION['**hidden**']['thelevel'];
$totaldureationinseconds = getnumberofsecondsfromlevel($level);
```

but i want to replace with an actual equation

like so;(of course this is wrong, this is just the example of the format i want it in  i.e an equation)

```
     $n = $_SESSION['**hidden**']['thelevel']; (level to get total value of 
                                                in seconds)
     $s = 60; (start level)
     $totaldureationinseconds = ($n * 10) + ($s * $n);
```

SOLVED by Gopalkrishna Narayan Prabhu :-)

```
    $totalseconds = 60 * $level + 5* (($level-1) * $level);
```

Comment: check the equation posted. Compare looping values and equation values they match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var total_secs = 0;
for(var i = 1; i<= n ;i++){
   total_secs = total_secs + (i*10) + 50;
}
```

for n= 1, total_secs = 0 + 10 + 50 = 60

for n= 2, total_secs = 60 + 20 + 50 = 130

and so on...

For a single equation:

```
 var n = level_number;

 total_secs = 60 * n + 5* ((n-1) * n);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you're justing looking for the equation

```
60 + ((levelN - 1) * 10)
```

Where `levelN` is the current level, starting at 1. If you make the first level 0, you can get rid of the `- 1` part and make it just

```
60 + (levelN  * 10)
```

Thought process:

What's the base/first number? What's the lowest it can ever be? 60. That means your equation will start with

```
60 + ...
```

Every time you increase the level, you add 10, so at some point you'll need something like `levelN * 10`. Then, it's just some fiddling. In those case, since you don't add any on the first left, and the first level is level 1, you just need to subtract 1 from the level number to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a really simple mathematical phrase (with factorial).

```
((n-1)! * 10) + (60 * n)
```

n is the level ofcourse.